# excel formula : Find uniques in one column depending on value of another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I can do this manually but I'm sure there is a formulaic way to do this.
Here is the data :

```
Column-A      Column-B      Column-C
C             Y   
D             
E             Y
F
E             Y
```

What I want to do is in 2 steps :
a.) Select all values in Column-A, where the corresponding value in Column-B is "Y".
b.) From the data selected from Column-A above, select only the unique values and put them in Column-C
c.) Hence the data in Column-C for the above data will be "C" & "E"

Any pointers ?

Comment: No, would avoid VBA if it can be done with simple formulaes

Comment: If you don't want VBA then superuser is a better place to ask Excel formula questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one option assuming you have excel 2007

Put this formula in C1

`=IFERROR(INDEX(A1:A5,MATCH("Y",B1:B5,0)),"")`

then this one in C2 copied down

`=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$5,MATCH(1,INDEX((B$1:B$5="y")*(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,A$1:A$5)=0),0),0)),"")`

You can do it in earlier versions but it requires some longer formulas to ensure that you don't get error values once valid matches are exhausted

Explanation:

Formula 1 uses `MATCH` to find the position of the first "y" in `B1:B5`, then `INDEX` returns the relevant value from `A1:A5`. If your columns were the other way round you could use `VLOOKUP`, `INDEX/MATCH` is a standard way to do a "left lookup".

Formula 2 uses `MATCH` to find the position of the first row where 2 conditions are satisfied, `B1:B5` = "y" and `A1:A5` <> a value already found. The values already found are in column C above so the `COUNTIF` function looks at the cells above and does a count for each value in column A within that range above (which expands as you drag the formula down) - a count of zero means that that value hasn't already been selected. Once `MATCH` identifies the row number `INDEX` takes the value from that row in column A.

Comment: Seems like its working ! 8-) thanks !! Now I need to understand what you've done 8-). That index function is new to me. Would you mind explaining why COUNTIF is used in C2 ?