# Return Match Values and also count this value for how many repeated in a range of cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I am straggling with some formula that I have a spreadsheet that contains two range of cells. What I want to do is, 
I would like to create a search Box that will search a value from Range A and if found return range B value and also will count of range B value is repeated.

Below image is for what I mean
[image]

I used INDEX, MATCH and also IF Functions :( but not really get what I wanted.
I am poor in formula, so it would be great if someone can figure out what kind of functions I should use for this.

Comment: Have you checked pivot table? Pivots can give you this and more control.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637318/excel-formula-find-uniques-in-one-column-depending-on-value-of-another-column

Comment: Thank you, I got the answer with PiVots.

Answer (score 1):

For information, it can be achieved through formula as below.

1. `E3` houses the value being searched for e.g. "A"
2. In cell `F3` insert following array formula which needs to be committed by hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> simultaneously.

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$1000,SMALL(IF(IFERROR(MATCH($E$3&$B$1:$B$1000,$A$1:$A$1000&$B$1:$B$1000,0),0)=ROW($B$1:$B$1000),ROW($B$1:$B$1000)),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")`

Copy down as much as you need.

> You need to adjust 1000 to suit your data. It should match last row.

3. In cell `G3` you can use following formula.

`=IF(F3="","",COUNTIFS(A:A,$E$3,B:B,F3))`

Copy down as much as you need.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will accept this answer after testing this.